# Html Template tag screws up the handlebar tags

Tags: html, handlebars.js, web-component, html-templates

This is my html featuring *"modern"* web component template:

```html
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">   
    <body>                  
                <template>                  
                    <table>
                        {{#each items}}
                        <tr>                            
                            <td>
                                {{email}}
                            </td>                           
                            <td>
                                {{phone}}
                            </td>                           
                        </tr>
                        {{/each}}
                    </table>                    
                </template>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Ans this is what I got in the browser (Chrome and Firefox):

```html
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US"><head></head><body>                    
                <template>                  
                    
                        {{#each items}}
                        
                        {{/each}}
                    <table><tbody><tr>                          
                            <td>
                                {{email}}
                            </td>                           
                            <td>
                                {{phone}}
                            </td>                           
                        </tr></tbody></table>                   
                </template>
        




</body></html>
```

As is clear, the handlebars curly tags are hoisted to the top. Are templates not supposed to keep the inner data intact for future rendering? Then are we left with the only option of using `<script type="shame-on-html">` instead of intuitive `<template>`?

(Please ignore this line: When browser will support dynamic web content more, and when the reign of React will end?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`template` tag content is not ignored by browsers.

> Think of a template as a content fragment that is being stored for subsequent use in the document. While the parser does process the contents of the  element while loading the page, it does so only to ensure that those contents are valid; the element's contents are not rendered, however.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

So the contents is parsed and validated. `table` elements have a specific list and order of [permitted content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table). So when the `template` content is parsed the unsupported content is removed from the `table`.

You can see the same behavior if you use `p` tags within a table.

```html
<template>                  
    <table>
        <p>
        <tr>                            
            <td>
                {{email}}
            </td>                           
            <td>
                {{phone}}
            </td>                           
        </tr>
        </p>
    </table>                    
</template>
```

An alternative approach would be to store the template in JavaScript and process it with Handlebars before inserting it into the DOM.

```html
<script>                  
    const template = `<table>
        {{#each items}}
        <tr>                            
            <td>
                {{email}}
            </td>                           
            <td>
                {{phone}}
            </td>                           
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>`;
</script>
```

Comment: No worries. I always used <script>, (plus we also have to add a made-up type to the script so that javascript ignores it ... )  just blew my mind when <template> turned not to be a simple content holder as we all need it for any type of templating ...